# What is the best article presenting counterarguments to a many-world interpretation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

I'd like to see a clear overview of why the [many-world interpretation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-worlds_interpretation) (WWI) of quantum is wrong, written by someone who believes that.

This would be aimed at a technically aware audience, yet as an overview, would have a broader view than just specific technical details. I'd like it to take on not only on philosopical issues like Ockham's Razor, but mathematical questions like the measurable distinction between entanglement and collapse.

Comment: There is a difference between something being wrong and something being not even wrong in physics. The multiworld interpretation is not even wrong... but it is completely useless, since it can't explain anything new while requiring an infinity potentiated to an infinity of universes to achieve exactly the same thing that can be had for absolutely free without it. As for collapse... there is no such thing. That's just a fudge for the folks who couldn't (or still can't) let go of classical particles.

Comment: @CuriousOne: Although there is no such thing as collapse, there is arguably still a measurement problem: why does a single realization of a measurement have a particular outcome. QM cannot predict the cause behind each outcome, however, it can predict the distribution. To me it seems it remains a matter of taste to reject that it is possible to find such a cause. However, I must admit that such a theory would probably be very complicated.

Comment: Why do coin flips have a particular outcome? Same thing.

Comment: @Bubble: Actually coin flips can be made quite predictable if the initial conditions and environment are well controlled, in contrast to quantum mechanical systems.

Comment: @Jasper Quite predictable is completely different from absolutely predictable. That is to say due to chaos and statistical physics even classical physics deals determinism a big blow. You may say that you can predict the outcome of the coin flip to arbitrary accuracy, but that is still different from 100.0% accuracy.

Comment: @Bubble: No really, this is just not correct. You don't need arbitrary accuracy to show that the coin will lie on one of two sides. You just need to be able to increase to sufficient accuracy, which can be rigorously specified. However, in quantum mechanics there seems to be no way to increase the accuracy. Nevertheless, there is no proof that it is impossible. In all other fields of science we do try to find causal relations between events, and it seems to me to be more a failure of imagination to suggest that in microscopic systems you cannot provide such relations.

Comment: @Jasper, you seem to be having issues with determinism failing in quantum physics. I have argued that it already fails in classical physics, at least if you want absolute determinism - some almost delta function on heads is still not a delta function on heads, its somewhat smeared and will always be smeared until you make a "measurement" and look at the coin. Quantum physics is perfectly casual and the failure of determinism is both an empirical and mathematical fact.

Comment: @Bubble: Let's agree to disagree. I simply leave open what the nature of nature is and find it better to be agnostic about whether determinism is possible or not. In the end all I am saying is that there seems to be no reason to not try to find such an underlying theory, however complicated it might be. Such a theory would be more predictable, which is what science strives to do, since it can in principle predict the cause for each outcome. I reject your statement that it has been proven that this is impossible.

Comment: @CuriousOne OK, but this is a topic of debate in the academic community. Serious professors have argued both sides. So, if you think MWI is nonsense, could you refer me to a relevant article.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: There is not much of argument there. Nobody of importance disagrees that interpretation doesn't get you anywhere in physics. "So, if you think MWI is nonsense, could you refer me to a relevant article.": you need to read all the important physicists (e.g. the folks at CERN and in other labs who are doing the real work) who have NOT written a single line about it because they don't care. :-)

Comment: @CuriousOne 

>"because they don't care."

It seems that MWI is taken seriously enough by some leading physicists that *some* other leading serious physicist would bother to write an overview rebuttal.

Comment: From what I understand, MWI is simply the idea that observers of a superposition enter a superposition themselves rather than collapsing the superposition of the observed system. It's plausible and consistent, but it's not clear how it would be useful. Perhaps it could motivate you to increase the probability of agreeable macroscopic states, but you should be motivated to do so anyway, regardless of how many quantum states wind up being real. So I suppose the only real counter-argument is that there's no practical reason to care, which applies equally to all interpretations.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: If you are talking about the QM interpretation folks who still can't let go of a question that has been solved 80 years ago... they are not "leading" physicists. I talked to one of the more famous ones a few decades ago, and he told me in private that he felt that he had wasted part of his career on a topic that was not worth it. I doubt he would admit that in public, though.

Comment: @CuriousOne I really don't know who are leading physicists. But I know that many tenured professors in top universities -- which does NOT make them right, but does make their arguments part of the academic discourse worthy of debate -- have seriously discussed both sides of this issue. So, I want to see an overview of  discussion of the issue.

Comment: @JoshuaFox: Leading physicists are the ones who are successful in measuring new phenomena and in explaining them. Interpretation alone doesn't give rise to new phenomena. One can, of course, think up deformations of e.g. MWI and predict new phenomena which could be used to falsify or support the new theory, but that's not what we are talking about. I am fully in favor of that because it would be great if we could find corrections to QFT at the level of low energy physics. As you can see, the current experimental search at the TeV frontier has serious economic limits.

Comment: Note that the difference between CI and MWI is not purely an interpretational matter, they make different predictions for certain experiments. E.g. a real collapse of an isolated system would not be inconsistent with CI but it would be with MWI which predicts unitary time evolution. So, MWI is certainly falsifiable. Falsifying CI is also possible but this requires implementing an observer in a quantum computer performing a reversible measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some random references out of the top of my head. I recommend chapter 8 of the book of Schlosshauer - Decoherence and the Quantum-To-Classical Transition. Also in favor of the MWI, see the book by David Wallace - The emergent multiverse, which addresses also open problems and discusses some criticisms. Also see: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qm-manyworlds/#6 and references therein. An old article: http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9703089v1 . Note: I'm not a fan of the MWI.

Comment: Also see Steven Weinberg's book "Lectures on quantum mechanics" for a short discussion of MWI and its problems.

Comment: @Jaster, thank you. 

OK, Weinberg is anti-MWI.

I am reading Wallace, but he is pro-MWI (though there are two interludes with objections.) 

I am also aware of the "objections" section in the Stanford encyclopedia, but I'd prefer a focused article against MWI.

The arxiv article by Kent is from 1990. I'd prefer an up-to-date overview of the field by a strong advocate.

Is Schlosshauer anti-MWI? That's what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Joshua Fox: Schlosshauer is a good author and physicist as he does not lean any way strongly, but he just looks at their merit. The article by Kent should be useful, though, for a critical viewpoint. This might also be useful: http://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.76.1267

Comment: @JoshuaFox: So what experiment have any of these people done that has found more than one universe? :-)

Comment: None ;) But such discussions are more about consistency. The same can be said of the inside of a black hole, but we believe we can describe such a part of the universe by extrapolating from our well-established theories. The interpretation of MW is a matter of extreme extrapolation and you can disagree with the assumptions of the extrapolation. In the end, these kinds of discussions quite often do lead to interesting new insights.

Comment: Single world QM is perfectly self-consistent. It's just not consistent with the (psychological, not physical) need for a particle interpretation of physics, but then, neither is classical mechanics, if we are serious about it. Anyway, what interesting new insights did we gain from a multi-world interpretation?

Comment: @CuriousOne:Im not an advocate for MWI. But e.g. David Deutsch credits thinking in terms of the MWI as the source many of his quite influential work: first quantum algorithms, quantum error correcting codes, quantum computation. Also, the idea of many worlds had great influence in developing decoherence theory by Zeh and Zurek, which is a cornerstone in understanding the emergence of the classical world. Similarly, deBroglie-Bohm theory caused Bell to re-evaluate hidden variables. It is easy to dismiss ideas but they can have great effect because they cause researchers to think differently.

Comment: @Jasper: The emergence of classical physics from quantum mechanics was fairly obvious before Zeh and Zurek. Feynman, at latest, could derive a consistent understanding of the interplay between path integrals and classical action, and I think someone mentioned in a previous post that Dirac (?) had that figured out, already a few years earlier. That Deutsch feels more comfortable thinking in the language of MWI has little relevance for physics. Bells hidden variable work refines what we already knew: the world is not made of classical particles.

Comment: @CuriousOne: I think you are being overcritical. Zurek's and Zeh's work is definitely necessary to understand the preferred basis problem and to understand why macroscopic superpositions are hard to produce (the quantum-classical boundary). I think its still a scientific question to ask how single outcomes come about in a single experiment. If no theory can predict this, science should provide a theorem why this cannot be the case.

Comment: @Jasper: Don't get me wrong about Zeh and Zurek. I have been reading both (and then some). I value their work, it's just not correct to say that they were the first people to make solid connections between classical physics and quantum theory. The problem with much of this is that a lot of the "problems" with the interpretation of QM stem from false assumptions about the meaning of "particle" in classical mechanics (where it is defined by the dynamics of the center of mass of a system with negligibly exited internal degrees of freedom rather than "tiny balls").

Answer (score 7):

None of the interpretations are right or wrong, since they are interpretations of the same mathematical formalism which predict the same events. Interpretations are a philosophical adjunct that provides a "what is REALLY happening" view. If an interpretation is tested and shown to be wrong, then it is no longer an interpretation - just wrong physics. Similarly, I am not sure if any interpretation could ever be shown to be the correct one.

Comment: OK, but this is a topic of serious debate in the academic community. Respected professors have argued both sides. So, could you refer me to a relevant article?

Comment: @JoshuaFox: *but this is a topic of serious debate in the academic community* That doesn't contradict anything Dirk Bruere said. Interpretations have to do with the philosophy of science. Philosophy is a topic of serious debate, but it doesn't make testable predictions.

Answer (score -1):

MWI has issues with how the effect of a measurement causes the world (universe) to split into potentially an infinite number of copies of itself, each slightly different. How fast does the influence "rip" (tear?) through the Universe? At the speed of light? No, it would have to be faster otherwise ERP experiments would not work. So, instantaneously? But in whose frame of reference? 
Also, there would be Universes where every toss of a coin yields a HEAD, but everyone believes in probability theory.
MWI is a great devices for constructing Science Fiction stories, but not really viable IMHO. It confuses the sample space with reality.

Comment: It's not true that MWI requires FTL "splitting" to explain EPR correlations--it exploits a loophole in Bell's proof, namely his assumption of unique measurement results at each location. In contrast, the MWI assumes each experimenter measuring one member of an entangled pair splits locally into versions which see different results, the universe need not "decide" which versions of experimenter 1 get matched to which versions of experimenter 2 until there's been time for a signal moving at the speed of light or slower to pass between them. See http://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/9906007 for details.